# Call Recording not working

Tags: android, audio-recording, phone-call

I am developing call recording function for an app. When I use the Audio source as `VOICE_CALL` or `VOICE_UPLINK` or `VOICE_DOWNLINK`, then the output file is empty. when I change audio source to `MIC` then the file is created, But `MIC` does not record other side's voice. Can anyone help?